# What is this type of roof covering called

Tags: roofing

So, I built the framing for this structure some years ago not knowing exactly what it's called. Can anyone elaborate?

[image: Structure in question]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically a portico or bay window awning.

Comment: Thanks! Not asking about the materials as I built this some years ago. I just didn't know what it's proper name was.

Comment: Additional questions regarding clarification of the original question posting really should be in the comments under the question.

Comment: I don't really understand what your  saying? Can you maybe simplify Michael ? Sorry I just started my account today trying to get fully aquainted

Answer (score 0):

French mansard-style, hipped, bay roof.